# Laravel Query builder where() for when Product has to have multiple tags (with product_tags pivot table many-to-many)

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I am new to Laravel and I got a complicated query to build. I managed to sort it except for when a user asks for multiple tags (`tags = 1, 2, 3`). Product shown has to have all `tags` that the user asks (not only one or two but all of them).

I have the query in SQL (this example is two tags, I would switch it to different numbers based on how many tags are passed):

```
SELECT  m.*
FROM  meals m
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM meals_tags t
    WHERE m.id = t.meals_id AND
        t.tags_id IN (227,25)
    HAVING COUNT(1) = 2
);
```

This one works perfectly, but I have an issue when translating it to an Eloquent query builder `where` method.

I have another `where` method included in the same query so I want to attach this one as well.

I have tried this:

```
DB::table('meals')
    ->select('id')
    ->where(function ($query) use ($parameters) {
        if (isset($parameters['tags'])) {
            $array = explode(',', $parameters['tags']);
            $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                ->from('meals_tags')
                ->where('meals.id', '=', 'meals_tags.meals_id')
                ->whereIn('meals_tags.tags_id', $array)
                ->having(DB::raw('COUNT(1)'), '=', count($parameters['tags']));
        }
    });
```

But I can't find a way. New to Laravel and PHP.

Let's say I have table `meals` and `tags` with `meals_tags` to connect them (many to many).

---

`$paramaters` are comming from `GET (...?tags=1,2,3&lang=en&another=something...)`, they are an array of key-value pairs (`['tags' => '1,2,3', 'lang' => 'en']`)

`$parameters['tags']` is of type `string` with comma separated numbers (positive `integers` greater than `0`) so that I have the option to explode it if needed somewhere.

Comment: Please provide more information about where `$parameters` is coming from and what type of variable it is.

Comment: Edited with your comment request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have defined `belongsToMany` (Many-to-Many) `meal_tags` relationship on the `Meal` model, you can try

```php
Meal::select('id')
    ->when(
        $request->has('tags'),
        function($query) use ($request) {
            $requestedTagIds = explode(',', $request->tags);

            return $query->whereHas(
                'meal_tags', 
                fn ($query) => $query->whereIn('tags_id', $requestedTagIds),
                '=', 
                count($requestedTagIds)
            );
        }
    )
    ->get();
```

Comment: Works like a charm. For my situation, I am getting $request as a array not object so I had to change it to $request['tags'] instead of $request->tags (for anyone in the future that has the same issue). And for $request->has('tags'), I am using isset($request['tags']). Thank you for help :D